# How i set variable in XSL in for

Tags: arrays, variables, xsl-fo

Sry, when i don't i find answare, but i don't make correct question. I have APEX 4 and trying create report from multiarray select. For example data is:

```
Name1 Value1
Name1 Value2
Name1 Value3
Name1 Value4
Name2 Value5
Name2 Value6
Name2 Value7
```

and I need output in report:

```
-Name1
    --Value1
    --Value2
    --Value3
    --Value4
-Name2
    --Value5
    --Value6
    --Value7
```

I need do it in XSL similiar as php:

```
$x_key= '';
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) 
{ 
   if ($x_key != $key) {
       $x_key = $key;
       echo "-$key\n";
   } 
   echo "--$value\n"; 
}
```

My code possible is (but don't do it what I want):

```
    <xsl:variable name="NAMEOLD" select="X" />
    <xsl:for-each select="//ROWSET1_ROW[position()]">
        <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="NAME_NUMBER" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="NAME!=NAMEOLD">
                <xsl:variable name="NAMEOLD" select="NAME" />
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-transparent" >
                        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="align-left txt" keep-together.within-page="always">
                            <xsl:value-of select="NAME_NUMBER"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-transparent" >
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="align-left txt" keep-together.within-page="always">
                    <xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks for any clue or answer 
Stoupa101

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your input XML. The simplest solution is along the following lines (note this requires XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ROW" group-adjacent="name">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key"></h1>
  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()"/>
  <p><xsl:value-of select="value"/></p>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Don't try to do it the PHP way - there's no point writing low-level code when you have a high-level language.